# Identify C++ class members from asm listing

Tags: c++, assembly, decompiling, borland-c++

I'm trying to disassemble and understand an old game's launcher (asm listing at http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=6Z4Xu3Cg). It was built using Borland C++ 1995 and there are four classes with names and dtor addresses in the asm listing. How do I find out to which class the other functions belong? How do I identify the vtable? It should, after all, contain everything.

By the way, this is NOT about copy protection breaking. The game is so old, it doesn't have any form of protection. What I'm trying to do is the same thing as the OpenTTD devs did.

Thank you,
harddisk

Comment: Why do you assume all functions belong to classes?  C++ is a multi-paradigm language and allows non-member functions as per C.  Similarly, there may not be a vtable - they're only generated for classes with virtual functions, and those are only used for run-time polymorphism.  If the game has only 4 classes, it's as likely as not that they model orthogonal aspects of the system and have no inheritance relationship.  And vtable's only have pointers to the virtual functions (and perhaps RTTI) anyway - not a magic key to understanding the whole.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't contain *everything*. Every symbol that's not dynamically dereferenced probably has been striped. What a disassembler can do is identifying the typical structure of particular compiler's output and give it some meaning.

Comment: Is it at least safe to say that the code between the tpid structures does belong to the same class for Borland C++ compiler?

Comment: Dpending on how the linker works/worked one could assume this and maybe was right, but would not count on it. For example between two tpid structures you can find WinMain, a function definitely not part of a class. One important thing to understand is on the assembly level there are no classes. You got a bunch of structures containting the class member variables, and a bunch of functions which take a pointer to such structures. One class member variable is the pointer to the vtable.

Comment: what are the structures with the class member variables and how did you find them? The only thing I could find is dword_4038F8, which appears in every dtor and ctor...

Comment: Those structures are not to be found in the code. You may find static initializers for them. But to the CPU a structure is just a contigous piece of memory; what gives a structure its structure is the code that accesses it's members. So once can identify structures only from the context in which memory used by functions. For example you can trace which functions a pointer is passed to analyze which offsets to this pointer are accessed in which way be the functions. Good old plain code analysis. For this kind of thing IDA Pro has been developed.